# С#, HttpWebRequest, Cookie

Tags: c#, cookie, httpwebrequest

ответ возвращается, однако, если пароль и логин верны, то в заголовках ответа нет параметра Set-Cookie, как и самих куков. Есть ли тому конкретная причина, или нужно в вайршарк?

```
private async Task<HttpWebRequest> CreateRequest(string login, string pass)
 {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("site.com/site/site");
        request.Method = "POST";

        string uncoded =  $"somedata";
        byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(uncoded);

        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Host = "site.com";
        request.Referer = "site.com";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0";

        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        try
        {
            using (Stream dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
                dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        return request;
    }

    private async void GetCookie()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = await CreateRequest(login, password);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }
```

Comment: Как сервер себя ведет вы смотрели? Может он редирект делает, либо требует еще какой то параметр, вариантов уйма. P.S. Советую отказаться от `HttpWebRequest`, ибо данный класс является устаревшим в C#.

Comment: Сам сервер собран очень давно, прямого доступа к нему нет, увы

Comment: Я не про его исходники говорю, а про то, как он этот же запрос обработает в том же браузере или Postman, вы смотрели?